# Is this typical for a second semester calculus-based physics course?

Tags: electromagnetism, education

There is no physics equivalent of the Math Educators Exchange, so I hope this is an okay place to ask this question. I work as an undergraduate TA in a second semester calculus-based physics course (modeled after the textbook *University Physics*). The course is intended for engineering and physics majors.

We are in Week 12 of 15, and many students still do not know what it meant by ***dA***, as in the infinitesimal amount of area. Similarly, students still do not know about what "enclosed charge" means in relation to Gauss's Law for electric flux.

Students also did not understand the differences between an integral, a line integral, and a surface integral. Many could not evaluate the integral of only *dl* (which is just "l").

Is this typical, or is this a result of the lowering of student expectations? I looked at the exams, and one of the exam questions was "What is the magnitude of the unit vector **j**", and over 70% of the class got it wrong (it was multiple choice).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the knowledge base of a particular group of physics students and not about physics itself. If you'd like to talk about such topics, you might be interested in the main physics chat room - [here's a link to the h bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). That being said, it sounds to me like there has been 12 weeks of profound miscommunication between the course instructor and the students, but I'm not shocked to hear it.

Comment: What is a "undergraduate TA"? You seem to be assuming specific knowledge of the education of system of a specific country, while people posting here can be from anywhere. It'd help if you could provide additional details.

Comment: This is pretty common in introductory electromagnetism courses -- physics education research shows that students have a very very hard time understanding vector calculus unless you spend a lot of time on the basics, like reintroducing what unit vectors are.

Comment: @Miyase In the US, a TA is a “teaching assistant”, often a grad student, who helps a professor not by giving the main lectures but by answering students’ questions, tutoring them outside lectures, giving and grading quizzes, etc.

Comment: @knzhou These students have taken multivariable (vector) calculus, as it is a prerequisite, though. What gives?

Comment: @mrwillparker (a student myself commenting from observations of my peers) I think what students get out of a course wildly varies based off of both 1) the institution, and really 2) the student. For example, it seems like most students at my university come out of Linear Algebra knowing very, very little even though the course (in my opinion) went above what the average undergraduate Linear Algebra course offers. Also, the prerequisite that a student has taken may not be as thorough as when you took it. My MVC course covered barely anything (I know most the MVC I know from Griffith's Ch.1).

Comment: @Miyase To continue Ghost's comment, an "undergraduate TA" is someone who is not yet a grad student who is acting as a teaching assistant. A lot of schools in the US use both graduate and undergraduate students as TAs for introductory level classes. The rationale is that a graduate TA is too far removed from the material and likely too far removed from a typical student's misunderstanding as a grad student likely had no trouble at all understanding that introductory level material.

Comment: @J.Murray That 70% of the students got "What is the magnitude of the unit vector **j**" wrong is definitely indicative of profound miscommunication between the course instructor (and the instructor's teaching assistants) and the students.

Comment: @J.Murray There was an entire lecture dedicated to just unit vectors :(

Comment: What did they think the magnitude of a unit vector was?

Comment: @Ghoster the options were 0, 1, 5, 10, and -10, so the wrong answers were a mix of everything but 1. Only 40% of the students got it right. Also V = ? was a question that most got wrong too, with the options: V = EA, V = IR, V = 0